# Silex, передача объекта в конструктор

Tags: php, ооп, dependency-injection, silex

У меня класс контроллера, и я столкнулся с проблемой, как передать в конструктор собственно говоря объект `$mapper`, никто не подскажет, как это сделать?

```
class foo
{
   public function __construct(InterfaceMapper $mapper)
   {
         $this->mapper = $mapper;
   }
   public function index(Request $request, Application $app)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конструктор контроллера ничего передавать не надо.

Можно добавить класс InterfaceMapper в контейнер `$app`:

```
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['some_service'] = $app->share(function () {
    return new Service();
});
```

либо присвоить значение

```
$app['mapper'] = $mapper;
```

и использовать в контроллере `$app['mapper']`

подробные примеры есть в документации
http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/services.html

Comment: спасибо огромное, а то я сижусь и мучаюсь, что делать и как писать правильно.

Answer (score 0):

```
class foo
{
   public function __construct(InterfaceMapper $mapper)
   {
         $this->mapper = $mapper;
   }
   public function index(Request $request, Application $app)
}
$mapper = ...;
$foo = new foo($mapper);
```

Так что ли?

Comment: спасибо, но я еще не отупел настолько. Вопрос silex исключителньо. Там контроллеры map-ятся к роутерам, таким вот образом.  $app->get('/', 'Controllers\IndexController::index')->bind('homepage'); и я хз как передать в конструктор индексаконтроллера нужные значение